# Finding bit positions of '1' in DES Encryption

Tags: encryption, des, decryption

In DES encryption, the IP table is shown. If the input
given in hexadecimal is "0020 0940 0000 F008", which
are the bit positions of "1" after the IP stage ?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se. Do you know how to use this table?

Comment: well, I have studied it theoretical but never used it in a question like that. I am student still btw.

Comment: Hints: in the [original document](https://csrc.nist.gov/files/pubs/fips/46-3/final/docs/fips46-3.pdf#page=15), this table is followed by: "That is the permuted input has bit 58 of the input as its first bit, bit 50 as its second bit, and so on with bit 7 as its last bit". Also, bits are numbered starting from 1 in reading order per big-endian binary representation. I think the question really is: what is the bit numbers of bits that are "1" in the output of IP for the stated input of IP.

Comment: @Bassel1000 if you wish you can answer your question.

Comment: if I can answer my question, why would I be asking?

Comment: @Bassel1000 you are given hint to learn so if you learned you can answer, this is common and we encourage people about this.

Comment: See the answer to [External data loading in DES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67031) showing data flow to and from a byte wide interface in a hardware implementation. Note the use of big-endian bit ordering in the byte wide interface where the MSB is bit position 1 and the LSB is 8. The inputs bytes are ordered 1 - 8, and the difference between the Initial Permutation and Inverse IP is a L and R swap after 16 rounds.  There's enough information in that first image to produce an answer.

Comment: ok thanks @user16145658