# DES Encryption: Looking for results for each round of encryption/decryption to debug code

Tags: des

I've been searching for a few days in different forums trying to find an example of DES that gives the key/output values for all 16 layers. I found one that gives the encryption which helped me fix that part, but my decryption isn't working correctly. It's easier to debug if I know what I'm aiming for.

Is there someplace that has all the encryption/decryption round outputs that I can look at?

Should they be the same only backward? Decryption round 1 output = encryption round 16 output?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/65996/64-des-full-example-with-all-the-stages/66095#66095

Answer (score 1):

> Should they be the same only backward? Decryption round 1 output = encryption round 16 output?

Yes, that is correct; the decryption subkeys are exactly the encryption subkeys in the opposite order.

I don't have the per-round test vectors you were asking for, but I can make this suggestion: if you have DES working in the encrypt direction, you can generate the test vector yourself; recording the state of the block after each round.  Then, when you attempt to decrypt the block, the per-round block state is supposed to traverse the same path backwards; for example, if the block state after encryption round 15 was X, then the block after after decryption round 1 should also be X.  If decryption isn't working, then somewhere during the cipher it went wrong; by looking at the per-round states, you should be able to narrow it down to a specific round.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your explanation. I'll use that and the links above to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Page 155-156 of https://academic.csuohio.edu/yuc/security/Chapter_06_Data_Encription_Standard.pdf seems to have a full set of round on round data for one example.

There’s another example at the end of this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-encryption-standard-des-set-1/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the links. (SE changed my name/account an isn't counting my upvotes.)